# In writing dates, when should "last" or "on" be used?

Tags: word-usage

Please enlighten me about the difference in using "last" and "on" when writing dates.  For example, which one would be correct: "I attended the meeting on December 14, 2014." Or, "I attended the meeting last December 14, 2014." I can't find any resource for answers. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There would be nothing wrong with using *last* in this example, but it would be more usual (in the UK anyway) to use *on*.

The latter case would always imply the most recent 'last' instance of that date unless you specified that it was a previous 14 December, e.g. of 2013.

*Last* is more often used with days - *I went there last Tuesday*, but you can also say *I went there on Tuesday*. There is really no rule here but it just becomes a matter of usage. Perhaps 'last' emphasises that it was the most recent past Tueday, and not a previous Tuesday.

The same sort of principles apply to using 'last' with month. E.g *I went there last December* versus *I went there in December*.

Comment: small typo "Tueday", penultimate one in third para.

Comment: My hunch is that there's really no hard-fast rules on these. I've been trying to look for resources to validate these rules on usage: last December 14 and on December 14, 2014, but nothing comes up. Your answer is very helpful. Thank you!