# last <date> vs on <date>

Tags: dates

Is it more correct to say:

> Your service expired ***last*** June 1, 2017

as opposed to

> Your service expired ***on*** June 1, 2017

If yes, why?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/224398/in-writing-dates-when-should-last-or-on-be-used

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I believe that saying

> Your service expired **on** June 1, 2017

would be more correct, since there is no other **June 1, 2017**, so why would it be necessary to clarify that it was **last June 1, 2017**?

It would however, be more proper to use **last** if you omitted the year, or, in other words, you stated:

> Your service expired **last** June 1st.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, ***last*** is a relative term -- it describes the most recent event that would fit.  For example, one might say *I saw him last Tuesday*.  Here, last indicates that the Tuesday you're referring to is the most recent previous one, not some other Tuesday.  If you are using a full date (month, day, and year) then ***last*** is not necessary.  *Your service expired last June* would make sense; your example, while not grammatically wrong, is awkward.

On the other hand, ***on*** refers to a specific date (identified either by using a full date as you have or by context.)  If a full date is not specified, then it is generally assumed to apply to either the most recent or next event.  *He will arrive on Tuesday* would imply the next occurring Tuesday whereas *He arrived on Tuesday* implies the most recently occurring Tuesday (due to the use of past tense.)

So, to sum up:

**Last** -- the most recent occurrence, used without a full date
**On** -- a specific date, identified either by the use of a full date or by context.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends how recently the service actually expired. If in the relatively recent past, say less than six months, then I think "Your service expired on June 1, 2017" is better. "Last June 1, 2017" implies that it was last year, or in the more distant past.